# Animated show with elemental monsters/villains. One episode involves a main character trapped in a building with toxic green smoke

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

I watched an animated show about 7/8 years ago, which probably would've been made around then. It had elemental monsters/villains in it, and I think the elements were: Wind, Water, Fire, Earth, Dark and Light.

I think there were three heroes and the elements as main characters. One hero was a girl the other two, I think, were male. The monsters weren’t summoned or anything, but they would try to attack the heroes and the regular people, and the show was a bit futuristic.

I think I remember a bit of one episode where a main character (hero) was trapped in a building and there were toxic chemicals in there like a green smoke.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it was made? Also, can you describe the appearance and sex of the main characters, and tell us how many main characters there were? Also, was this one of those shows where people transform into monsters, one where people summon monsters and have them battle in arenas, or something else?

Comment: I think I would’ve watched it about 7/8 years ago and it probably would’ve been made around then. I don’t remember appearance but there were I think three heroes and the elements as main characters 1 hero was a girl the other 2 I think were male. The monsters weren’t summoned or anything but they would try attack the heroes and the regular people and the show was a bit futuristic. Hope this helps

Comment: It’s not Captain Planet is it?

Comment: No it is not Captain Planet

Comment: @MissouriSpartan no, in Captain Planet there's only five elements (Heart, Fire, Water, Earth, Wind) and those are the elements of the Rings of Power that the protagonists use per se or to summon Captain Planet ("By the union of your powers, I am the Captain Planet).

Comment: Maybe this could be one of the _Gormiti_ series (either the [2008 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gormiti_(2008_TV_series)), the [2012 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gormiti_Nature_Unleashed), or the [2018 one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gormiti_(2018_TV_series)))? Though in those series there are _7_ kinds of element-based monsters, rather than 6: Forest, Sea, Earth, Air, Light, Volcano, Darkness.